# Setting Chrome/Chromium audio sample rate when there is no sound device

Tags: chromium

Using Ubuntu under Docker, I am running Chrome to render some web pages as video with their audio.

This is working fine, but the audio sample rate is fixed to 44.1 kHz.  This is a VM with no audio device.  There is no Pulseaudio daemon that I can see, or anything like that.  How can I set the audio sample rate of the browser?

Note, `--alsa-fixed-output-sample-rate 48000` has no effect.

Comment: For which API exactly? You should be able to force the sample rate of an AudioContext, by passing `{ sampleRate: 48000 }` to the constructor, but I'm not sure this would really help you.

Comment: Don't know if that helps - but if you use a snd-aloop device it may help to first connect to it with 48000 hz before using chromium because that should determine the sample rate of the device.

Comment: Hi @Kaiido, I'm using the tab capture API and other media APIs unrelated to the Web Audio API unfortunately.  Thanks for the suggestion though!

Answer (score 1):

First try re-installing alsa and pulseaudio:

```
sudo apt-get remove --purge alsa-base pulseaudio indicator-sound
sudo apt-get install alsa-base pulseaudio indicator-sound
sudo alsa force-reload
```

I know you said you can't find a pulseaudio daemon - I expect you may need it present, and will need to install it. This first step should do that for you.

If that doesn't work, try killing pulseaudio:

```
killall pulseaudio; rm -r ~/.config/pulse/* ; rm -r ~/.pulse*
```

Hopefully that works for you!

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem. It ended up being that my system was trying to put Chrome's sound through the HDMI even though the HDMI cord was not plugged in at the time. Presumably, this could happen with any audio output device. The sound settings `Ubuntu` offers didn't show this nor let me change it for the individual application, but `pavucontrol` did.

To install `pavucontrol` from the Terminal:

`sudo apt-get install pavucontrol`

To open `pavucontrol` from the Terminal:

*Select the "Playback" menu and make sure that you have it set to Show Applications. Now, start playing something from Google Chrome. It will show up there, and it will show what output device is being used for Google Chrome. Make sure it is set to the output device you are trying to use.*